# How to find nearest last/next date for a given day name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sql-function

I'm trying to write a function in SQL to return nearest last or next date for a given day name.

For example, today is Wed 18/05/16, I want to pass the function day='Mon' period='next' and return 23/5/16 or, day='Mon' period='last' to return 16/05/16.

I've attempted the following but seems too clunky as I still need to add logic for nearest date and next week's date.

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to best approach this?

Thanks in advance.

```
DECLARE @theWeekday VARCHAR(3) = 'Sun';
DECLARE @dayDiff INT;
DECLARE @dayOfWeek TINYINT
DECLARE @todayOfWeek TINYINT

--return thursday last week select DATEADD(DAY, ((DATEDIFF(DAY, '19000104', getdate()) / 7) * 7) hence why i have @dayOfWeekThu
DECLARE @dayOfWeekThu INT = 4;

SET @dayOfWeek = CASE @theWeekday
         WHEN 'Mon' THEN 1
         WHEN 'Tue' THEN 2
         WHEN 'Wed' THEN 3
         WHEN 'Thu' THEN 4
         WHEN 'Fri' THEN 5
         WHEN 'Sat' THEN 6
         WHEN 'Sun' THEN 7
END


If @dayOfWeekThu < @dayOfWeek
BEGIN
    SET @dayDiff = @dayOfWeekThu-@dayOfWeek;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @dayDiff = ABS(@dayOfWeek-@dayOfWeekThu);
END

select DATEADD(DAY, ((DATEDIFF(DAY, '19000104', getdate()) / 7) * 7) - @dayDiff, '19000104')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the idea i have is to get the date of the first day of the current week, after that it is fairly simple.

```
declare @wk int  
       ,@yr int 
       ,@Date datetime
       ,@dayOfWeek int
       ,@theWeekday VARCHAR(3) = 'fri'
       ,@Period varchar(10) ='Next'


   set @yr = year(getdate())
   set @wk = DATEPART( wk, getdate())-1
   set @Date =  dateadd (week, @wk, dateadd (year, @yr-1900, 0)) - 4 -
         datepart(dw, dateadd (week, @wk, dateadd (year, @yr-1900, 0)) - 4) +2

SET @dayOfWeek = CASE @theWeekday
         WHEN 'Mon' THEN 0
         WHEN 'Tue' THEN 1
         WHEN 'Wed' THEN 2
         WHEN 'Thu' THEN 3
         WHEN 'Fri' THEN 4
         WHEN 'Sat' THEN 5
         WHEN 'Sun' THEN 6
         end


if @Period = 'Next'
begin

set @Date = dateadd("dd",@dayOfWeek,dateadd(wk, 1, @Date))
end

else 

begin
set @Date = dateadd("dd",@dayOfWeek,dateadd(wk, 0, @Date))
end

select @Date
```